# Custom Conditional Format Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to format a cell if it is empty and another cell contains an specified value.

For example[image]

IF(A = "Type 1" AND B = "")
  THEN FORMAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Conditional formatting on A1.

Apply to range:

A1:A

Custom formula is:

```
=and(A1="Type 1",B1="")
```